# Phonegap / swipe code

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I make a webapp with PhoneGap.

The problem is that the sideswipe gesture only works on the first page and when I go to another page I have to refresh that page before it works again.

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('swipeleft', "#page1", function() {
   $( "body" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#page2" );
  });
  $(document).on('swiperight', "#page2", function() {
   $( "body" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#page1" );
  });
  $(document).on('swipeleft', "#page2", function() {
   $( "body" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#page3" );
  });
  $(document).on('swiperight', "#page3", function() {
   $( "body" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#page2" );
  });
  $(document).on('swipeleft', "#page3", function() {
   $( "body" ).pagecontainer( "change", "pippo.html" );
  });
 </script>
```

When i load pippo.html, the swipe didn't work. Idea?
Thanks!